# how to understand Keras pretrained weight file? (I get non-sense as output)

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch, transformer-model, pre-trained-model

I'm new in both Tensorflow and Pytorch and I'm trying to implement Pytorch version of an available code in Tensorflow.
Pretrained weight file of the TF code is available and I was hoping to be able to load this weights on my Pytorch version. however, I get *UnpicklingError: invalid load key, 'H'* when I was trying to load this weights using:

```
weight_file = "pretrained.h5"
model.load_state_dict(torch.load(weight_file ))
```

I tried to print weights using:

```
file = h5py.File(weight_file , 'r')
    for key in file.keys():
        print(key, file[key])
    file.close()
```

and I got hundreds of lines in the output and I can't understand it (I couldn't put all of the output here cause it was too long):

```
add_loss <HDF5 group "/add_loss" (0 members)>
add_loss_1 <HDF5 group "/add_loss_1" (0 members)>
add_loss_10 <HDF5 group "/add_loss_10" (0 members)>
add_loss_11 <HDF5 group "/add_loss_11" (0 members)>
add_loss_12 <HDF5 group "/add_loss_12" (0 members)>
add_loss_13 <HDF5 group "/add_loss_13" (0 members)>
add_loss_14 <HDF5 group "/add_loss_14" (0 members)>
add_loss_15 <HDF5 group "/add_loss_15" (0 members)>
add_loss_16 <HDF5 group "/add_loss_16" (0 members)>
add_loss_17 <HDF5 group "/add_loss_17" (0 members)>
add_loss_18 <HDF5 group "/add_loss_18" (0 members)>
add_loss_19 <HDF5 group "/add_loss_19" (0 members)>
add_loss_2 <HDF5 group "/add_loss_2" (0 members)>
add_loss_20 <HDF5 group "/add_loss_20" (0 members)>
add_loss_21 <HDF5 group "/add_loss_21" (0 members)>
...
concatenate <HDF5 group "/concatenate" (0 members)>
concatenate_1 <HDF5 group "/concatenate_1" (0 members)>
concatenate_2 <HDF5 group "/concatenate_2" (0 members)>
concatenate_3 <HDF5 group "/concatenate_3" (0 members)>
dense_714 <HDF5 group "/dense_714" (1 members)>
dense_715 <HDF5 group "/dense_715" (1 members)>
dense_716 <HDF5 group "/dense_716" (1 members)>
dense_717 <HDF5 group "/dense_717" (1 members)>
dense_718 <HDF5 group "/dense_718" (1 members)>
dense_719 <HDF5 group "/dense_719" (1 members)>
dense_720 <HDF5 group "/dense_720" (1 members)>
dense_721 <HDF5 group "/dense_721" (1 members)>
dense_722 <HDF5 group "/dense_722" (1 members)>
...
dropout_538 <HDF5 group "/dropout_538" (0 members)>
dropout_539 <HDF5 group "/dropout_539" (0 members)>
dropout_540 <HDF5 group "/dropout_540" (0 members)>
dropout_541 <HDF5 group "/dropout_541" (0 members)>
dropout_542 <HDF5 group "/dropout_542" (0 members)>
dropout_543 <HDF5 group "/dropout_543" (0 members)>
dropout_544 <HDF5 group "/dropout_544" (0 members)>
dropout_545 <HDF5 group "/dropout_545" (0 members)>
dropout_546 <HDF5 group "/dropout_546" (0 members)>
...
input_4 <HDF5 group "/input_4" (0 members)>
input_5 <HDF5 group "/input_5" (0 members)>
input_6 <HDF5 group "/input_6" (0 members)>
lambda_10 <HDF5 group "/lambda_10" (0 members)>
lambda_100 <HDF5 group "/lambda_100" (0 members)>
lambda_101 <HDF5 group "/lambda_101" (0 members)>
lambda_102 <HDF5 group "/lambda_102" (0 members)>
lambda_103 <HDF5 group "/lambda_103" (0 members)>
lambda_104 <HDF5 group "/lambda_104" (0 members)>
lambda_105 <HDF5 group "/lambda_105" (0 members)>
lambda_106 <HDF5 group "/lambda_106" (0 members)>
lambda_107 <HDF5 group "/lambda_107" (0 members)>
...
masking_models <HDF5 group "/masking_models" (4 members)>
masking_models_1 <HDF5 group "/masking_models_1" (4 members)>
masking_models_10 <HDF5 group "/masking_models_10" (4 members)>
masking_models_100 <HDF5 group "/masking_models_100" (4 members)>
masking_models_101 <HDF5 group "/masking_models_101" (4 members)>
masking_models_102 <HDF5 group "/masking_models_102" (4 members)>
...
output_0 <HDF5 group "/output_0" (1 members)>
output_1 <HDF5 group "/output_1" (1 members)>
output_10 <HDF5 group "/output_10" (1 members)>
output_11 <HDF5 group "/output_11" (1 members)>
output_12 <HDF5 group "/output_12" (1 members)>
output_13 <HDF5 group "/output_13" (1 members)>
output_14 <HDF5 group "/output_14" (1 members)>
output_15 <HDF5 group "/output_15" (1 members)>
...
position_embedding <HDF5 group "/position_embedding" (1 members)>
position_embedding_1 <HDF5 group "/position_embedding_1" (1 members)>
position_embedding_2 <HDF5 group "/position_embedding_2" (1 members)>
tf.compat.v1.transpose <HDF5 group "/tf.compat.v1.transpose" (0 members)>
tf.compat.v1.transpose_1 <HDF5 group "/tf.compat.v1.transpose_1" (0 members)>
tf.compat.v1.transpose_10 <HDF5 group "/tf.compat.v1.transpose_10" (0 members)>
tf.compat.v1.transpose_100 <HDF5 group "/tf.compat.v1.transpose_100" (0 members)>
tf.compat.v1.transpose_101 <HDF5 group "/tf.compat.v1.transpose_101" (0 members)>
...
tf.expand_dims <HDF5 group "/tf.expand_dims" (0 members)>
tf.expand_dims_1 <HDF5 group "/tf.expand_dims_1" (0 members)>
tf.expand_dims_10 <HDF5 group "/tf.expand_dims_10" (0 members)>
tf.expand_dims_100 <HDF5 group "/tf.expand_dims_100" (0 members)>
tf.expand_dims_101 <HDF5 group "/tf.expand_dims_101" (0 members)>
...
tf.math.reduce_mean <HDF5 group "/tf.math.reduce_mean" (0 members)>
tf.math.reduce_mean_1 <HDF5 group "/tf.math.reduce_mean_1" (0 members)>
tf.math.reduce_mean_10 <HDF5 group "/tf.math.reduce_mean_10" (0 members)>
tf.math.reduce_mean_11 <HDF5 group "/tf.math.reduce_mean_11" (0 members)>
tf.math.reduce_mean_12 <HDF5 group "/tf.math.reduce_mean_12" (0 members)>
tf.math.reduce_mean_13 <HDF5 group "/tf.math.reduce_mean_13" (0 members)>
...
tf.math.square <HDF5 group "/tf.math.square" (0 members)>
tf.math.square_1 <HDF5 group "/tf.math.square_1" (0 members)>
tf.math.square_10 <HDF5 group "/tf.math.square_10" (0 members)>
tf.math.square_11 <HDF5 group "/tf.math.square_11" (0 members)>
tf.math.square_12 <HDF5 group "/tf.math.square_12" (0 members)>
tf.math.square_13 <HDF5 group "/tf.math.square_13" (0 members)>
tf.math.square_14 <HDF5 group "/tf.math.square_14" (0 members)>
tf.math.square_15 <HDF5 group "/tf.math.square_15" (0 members)>
tf.math.square_16 <HDF5 group "/tf.math.square_16" (0 members)>
tf.math.square_17 <HDF5 group "/tf.math.square_17" (0 members)>
...
tf.math.subtract <HDF5 group "/tf.math.subtract" (0 members)>
tf.math.subtract_1 <HDF5 group "/tf.math.subtract_1" (0 members)>
tf.math.subtract_10 <HDF5 group "/tf.math.subtract_10" (0 members)>
tf.math.subtract_11 <HDF5 group "/tf.math.subtract_11" (0 members)>
tf.math.subtract_12 <HDF5 group "/tf.math.subtract_12" (0 members)>
tf.math.subtract_13 <HDF5 group "/tf.math.subtract_13" (0 members)>
tf.math.subtract_14 <HDF5 group "/tf.math.subtract_14" (0 members)>
...
top_level_model_weights <HDF5 group "/top_level_model_weights" (0 members)>
transformer_block <HDF5 group "/transformer_block" (3 members)>
transformer_block_1 <HDF5 group "/transformer_block_1" (3 members)>
transformer_block_2 <HDF5 group "/transformer_block_2" (3 members)>
transformer_block_3 <HDF5 group "/transformer_block_3" (3 members)>
transformer_block_4 <HDF5 group "/transformer_block_4" (3 members)>
zero_padding1d <HDF5 group "/zero_padding1d" (0 members)>
zero_padding1d_1 <HDF5 group "/zero_padding1d_1" (0 members)>
zero_padding1d_10 <HDF5 group "/zero_padding1d_10" (0 members)>
zero_padding1d_100 <HDF5 group "/zero_padding1d_100" (0 members)>
zero_padding1d_101 <HDF5 group "/zero_padding1d_101" (0 members)>
zero_padding1d_102 <HDF5 group "/zero_padding1d_102" (0 members)>
zero_padding1d_103 <HDF5 group "/zero_padding1d_103" (0 members)>
zero_padding1d_104 <HDF5 group "/zero_padding1d_104" (0 members)>
...
```

Comment: Why don't you try loading weights with this 
tf.keras.Model.load_weights("pretrained.h5")

Comment: I intend to load these weights on a Pytorch model and I want to see its shape and values first.

Answer (score 1):

A trained model can have many weights and most of the time they are not interpretable by humans.

To be able to load the same model weights, first you have to make sure that both the Keras model and the PyTorch model have identical architectures.

The way I have seen people loading Keras model weights to PyTorch models is loading the weights and biases to layers one by one as in this image:
[Loading layer weights](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iL1dG.png)

You can check out this [blog post](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/load-keras-weight-to-pytorch-and-transform-keras-architecture-to-pytorch-easily-8ff5dd18b86b) for more, where the above image comes from

Comment: Thank you for your response. the architectures are as same as each other but first I need to know what's going on in this weight file. then I can load them one by one on my PyTorch model. I think I must give up on this and train the model from scratch again. Thank you